# Java - How to use a variable(non hardcoded) value in printf statement after decimal point?

Tags: java

I want to use a non hard coded value after decimal point in printf statement . Below is my code . Instead of 4 I want to set to x.

```
int x = sc.nextInt();
double d=103993d/33102d;
System.out.printf("%.4f", d);
```

Comment: `System.out.printf("%." + x + "f", d);` The format string is just a string that you can create any way you like, it doesn't have to be a string literal.

Answer (score 6):

Declare a variable and concatenate with the formatting string as below

```
double d=103993d/33102d;
int x=9;
System.out.printf("%."+x+"f", d);
```

OUTPUT:-

```
3.141592653
```

Answer (score 0):

Use String in printf.

```
    int x = sc.nextInt();
    double d=103993d/33102d;
    String s1 = Integer.toString(x);
    String s="%."+s1+"f";
    System.out.printf(s,d);
```